# How can I trim a field's value for display?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, on a content type's "Manage display" tab, it was possible to trim strings to a particular length, by setting the field's format to "Trimmed".

For example, you could trim a long text field to 200 characters for the Teaser mode.

This doesn't seem to be possible in Drupal 8 – I don't have the option to set a custom-field's format to "Trimmed". (The only option available is "Plain text".)

Has the "Trimmed" format indeed been removed for custom fields? If so, is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Your field type needs to be Text (formatted, long).
[image]

Then on the display settings page, you can change the display format to Trimmed, and edit the settings (by clicking the gear) to change the character limit.

[image]